# Is visual studio 2019 enterprise supports SharePoint 2016 development

Tags: development, 2016, visual-studio-2019

Is visual studio 2019 enterprise supports SharePoint 2016 development and if it is supports which version of office developer tools supports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any edition of the Visual Studio 2019 supports development of SharePoint solutions. Including Community edition. You can install the latest available Office Dev tools.

After installing Office Dev tools, you see will SharePoint Project templates. These project templates will be compatible with SharePoint 2013, 2016 and 2019.

Comment: Thanks also SP 2016 solutions under TFS is it also support check in and check out from VS 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Visual Studio 2019 will have SharePoint 2016 solution templates, it's compatible with SharePoint 2016:

[image]

[image]

Comment: please can share the link for office developer tools

Comment: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/office-tools/ this tool will be ready once installed Visual Studio 2019.